# distance from the origin in a simple random walk on $\mathbb Z^2$

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk

let $S_{n}= \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ be a simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$, with $S_0 = 0$.

$X_i = 1$ with probability $p$ and $X_i = -1$ with probability $1-p$.

It can be shown that 
$$\mathbb{P}(S_n=i\mid|S_n|=i, |S_{n-1}|=i_{n-1}, ..., |S_1|=i_1)= \frac{p^i}{p^i+(1-p)^i},$$

which means that having only $|S_n|=i$, one can calculate the probability of being in state $S_n=i$ (and therefore $S_n=-i$). From here, it is easy to show that $|S_n|$ is a markov chain.

I'm trying to show that the same is true for a (not necessarily symmetric) simple random walk  on $\mathbb{Z^2}$  starting from the origin. In other words, I want to show that distance from the origin at each step is a markov chain.

The argument above does not seem to be extendable here, since there may be $k>1$ points with integer coordinates for a given distance from the origin and $k$ depends on the distance.

Comment: do you have a reference for how the "it can be shown" is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. For instance, you have different options for the future whether you're at $(3,4)$ or $(5,0)$, and you can tell which one you're at by looking at the past, so the process is not memoryless.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. you also have different options whether you're at $-5$ of $5$ in the 1-D case, but this does not mean that $|S_n|$ is not a markov process.

Comment: @SSepehr: No, in that case you don't have different options. You have exactly the same options of moving to $|S_{n+1}|=4$ or to $|S_{n+1}|=6$ in both cases.

Comment: @SSepehr: And the other half of the argument also doesn't work in that case: You can't tell which one you're at by looking at the past.

Comment: @SSepehr: More formally, $0=\textsf P(|S_{n+1}|=6\mid|S_n|=5\land |S_{n-1}|=4\sqrt2)\ne\textsf P(|S_{n+1}|=6\mid|S_n|=5\land |S_{n-1}|=4)$.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. This was actually the second part of a question, and I didn't expect it to be wrong.

Comment: @joriki Dear Joriki, I was wondering whether you knew of studies where the mean squared displacement between two random walkers in finite 2D systems is studied? I'd be very curious to find out about them.